# How to create a responsive design in my case?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create 5 absolute positioned elements in my app.

The problem is I need to make them responsive for desktop and ipad.

I have something like:

```
<div class='container wrapper'>
    <a id='link1' href='#'><img src='img1.png'/></a>
    <a id='link2' href='#'><img src='img2.png'/></a>
    <a id='link3' href='#'><img src='img3.png'/></a>
    <a id='link4' href='#'><img src='img4.png'/></a>
    <a id='link5' href='#'><img src='img5.png'/></a>
</div>


.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    display:-webkit-box;
    top:10%;
    left:5%;
}

#link1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    left: 0;
}
#link2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 350px;
}
#link3{
    position: absolute;
    top: 280px;
    left: 700px;
}
#link4{
    position: absolute;
    top: 600px;
    left: 580px;
}
#link5{
    position: absolute;
    top: 580px;
    left: 180px;
}
```

It looks fine in my desktop with certain resolution but didn't work well with small resolution and ipad. I was wondering if there are anyways to fix this. Thanks so much!

Comment: Any specific reason making these links in absolute position?

Comment: It doesn't follow the regular flows. only absolute position can make it work.

Comment: create separate css for ipad and desktop browsers

Comment: yes, you need to write another css for iPad and target them via media queries only.

Comment: Can you add this in jsfiddle??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two divs and place content in inner div. If screen change, content will fit based on size and asjust width as you need

```
#outerdiv{
    width:100%;
}
#innerdiv{
    width:50%;
    height:100%
}
```

But best solution will be use media queries

```
@media (min-width:320px) { /* smartphones, portrait iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones (Android) */ }
@media (min-width:480px) { /* smartphones, Android phones, landscape iPhone */ }
@media (min-width:600px) { /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, e-readers (Nook/Kindle), landscape 800x480 phones (Android) */ }
@media (min-width:801px) { /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1025px) { /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ }
```